# how to turn on/off round slider button in case of value 1 and 0 fetched from db

Tags: php, checkbox, sqlite

```
   <div id="checkbox-container">

   <td><label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" name="check" id="option1" <?php if ($row['activate'] == 1) { 'checked="checked"'; }  ?>onclick="myFunction()"><span class="slider round">&nbsp; <p id="text" style="display:none"></p></span></label></td>
    </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWkb5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. You was missing `echo` and besides that - value for attribute 'checked' is redundant, it's enough to emit that attribute without value:

```
<?php if ($row['activate'] == 1) { echo 'checked '; }  ?>
```

Comment: doesn't make any change mate still i am not getting the desire result. it is getting turn off when data is 1 on database. :(

Comment: I checked online - it works. Put `var_dump($row['activate'])` somewhere in code before emitting checked attribute. What output of var_dump do you see ?